# Wpf data visualisation last version?

Tags: wpf, data-visualization

Can someone provide me link to the latest wpf datavisualisation version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most recent is [Release 4 (from April 20, 2010)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx).